# error TS2559: Type '"/phones"' has no properties in common with type 'IRoute'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

When I tried to upgrade the application (phoneCat apllication) from AngularJS to Angular I got this error. I tried with several errors but same error happened.

```
error TS2559: Type '"/phones"' has no properties in common with type 'IRoute'.

         otherwise('/phones');
                 ~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm not much familiar for both technologies AngularJS and Angular. If you know any solution please let me know.

Comment: can you add minimal reproduce steps or create a sample project in stackblitz.com and share it here?

Comment: It's very difficult to say because there's no code here, but you're using a string and it's looking for something that implements IRoutes. You will likely have to create some sort of JavaScript object and put that path as a value to some key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Your question is difficult to answer as there isn't any code to look at. When asking a question, it would be helpful to include:

1. the code in question (if you know)
2. the error in question
3. what you have already tried
4. versions of software (angular versions vary GREATLY 2-7ish; every major revision is a pretty big change.)

The issue appears to be coming from the fact that you are trying to call a function that is looking for an object that implements the `IRoute` interface, but you are giving it a string object. Looking at the Route Object (https://angular.io/api/router/Route), you may have to create some object:

```
{
    "path": "/phones"
}
```

If you just added the routing module, you may look at angular tutorials on angular routing. Here is some reference info:
https://ngrefs.com/latest/router/route-interface

```
...
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'team/:id',
    component: Team,
    children: [{
      path: 'user/:name',
      component: User,
    }],
  },
]),
```

You will notice they have a `path` key and a value for it.